# LDAP result code 32 - noSuchObject] NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST

Tags: ldap, apacheds, apache-directory

When adding a New Context Entry to a Root DSE, I get an error and can't figure out how to resolve it?
Could anyone help, please?

I am trying to add New Context Entry to a Root DSE, with dc=domain,dc=local as distinguished name

The error says:
Error while creating entry

```
\[LDAP result code 32 - noSuchObject\] NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
  org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.StudioLdapException:  \[LDAP result code 32 - noSuchObject\] NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
  Message ID : 32
  Add Request :
  Entry
  dn\[n\]: dc=domain,dc=local
  objectClass: domain
  objectClass: top
  dc: domain
  : ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=domain,dc=local
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.toStudioLdapException(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1350)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.access$2(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1342)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$6.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:912)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1261)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1209)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.createEntry(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:924)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.createEntry(CreateEntryRunnable.java:206)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.run(CreateEntryRunnable.java:123)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:129)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
  Caused by: org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapNoSuchObjectException: NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
  Message ID : 32
  Add Request :
  Entry
  dn\[n\]: dc=domain,dc=local
  objectClass: domain
  objectClass: top
  dc: domain
  : ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=domain,dc=local
  at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.ResultCodeEnum.processResponse(ResultCodeEnum.java:2024)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkResponse(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1337)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.access$6(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1333)
  at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$6.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:908)
  ... 7 more

\[LDAP result code 32 - noSuchObject\] NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST
Message ID : 32
Add Request :
Entry
dn\[n\]: dc=domain,dc=local
objectClass: domain
objectClass: top
dc: domain
: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=domain,dc=local
```

Comment: What LDAP server are you using, and is the context 'dc=domain,dc=local' already configured on the server?